# Sync Google Fusion Table with MySql DB

Tags: mysql, google-fusion-tables

So... I have been looking around and cannot find any way to accomplish this so I thought I would try here. I am looking for a means to dynamically "sync"/update a google fusion table with data stored inside a MySQL DB. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a prefab sync solution for fusion tables: its a bit of an odd use case, so you'll probably need to set that up yourself. The [SQL API samples](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code#sql) cover the bits you need to do inserts/updates/deletes: you'll need to do the sync logic yourself though.